# How to join two Cisco SG200 switches together

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan

I would like to extend a VLAN on Switch 1, to Switch 2, so could I simply use a crossover cable or a normal cat52/rj45 cable to connect a port on each switch together and then assign the two connected ports to the same VLAN (ID22)?#

P.S These switches are not connected together at all at the moment - are there any other connections for this I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're doing, so I'll answer the questions I can see:

**Switch 2 Needs To Operate On VLAN22**

If Switch 2 and everything that connects to it needs to be on VLAN22 then you simply need to connect any port on Switch 2 to a port on Switch 1 that has VLAN22 assigned. Assuming Switch 2 is currently not configured / at factory defaults you won't need to do anything on Switch 2.

This way, Switch 2 doesn't care or know about VLAN's - just like connecting a PC to an access port.

**Switch 2 has devices connected to it that need to be on various VLANS**

If want to extend your entire VLAN infrastructure to Switch 2 along with the option to assign different VLAN's to different ports on Switch 2 then you need to define a [trunk port](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=29803&seqNum=3) on each switch and connect them together using those.

You could then use [Cisco VTP](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk689/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094c52.shtml) to set up VLAN's on the second switch.

**Which Cable?**

Electronically speaking, because these are 'like' devices (I.e., two switches rather than a switch and a PC, or a switch and a router) you should be using a crossover cable. That said, for completeness, some devices will auto-negotiate using [AutoMDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX) and compensate which allows you to use either cable. This is absolutely fine to do, but it's important that you understand why (I.e., the port recognises that it has a similar device connected and switches accordingly) and that the end result is the same.

Comment: Thank you, that were very clear, that has saved me several hours of pain. Thank you! :)